# What type of data-structure is the Finalizer Queue?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have been debugging a heavy .NET WPF app in WinDbg and noticed that there are almost a million weak-references in the finalizer queue, the vast majority from bindings (which came as a shock to me). Since a Full GC involves comparing the full graph of rooted references against those in the finalizer queue I presume that the finalizer queue must be a HashSet (O(1)) or sorted list (O(log n)); I can't imagine it being an array for obvious performance reasons. Does anyone know what the data structure really is?

Comment: The CoreCLR is open source now, you might be able to glean more information from that: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr , specifically: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/finalizerthread.cpp

Comment: I would assume its a priority queue of sorts, i.e. it's a binary tree.

Comment: @JohnKoerner The .NET core implementation available on GitHub is incomplete, Microsoft hasn't added everything to  the GitHub repository yet.  Seems the GC related code isn't there yet.